# How to dump the local variables of a method (get their names, types, and values)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I am in the process of attempting to write an error handler for a home project that will sit in the `Catch ex` block of a sub or function and when triggered, write to an error log. Most of the work is done, but for inspiration, I was checking some old websites I wrote and they use a combination of `var_dump` and `print_r` (in PHP) to display the declared variables and their contents.  I would like to add this functionality into my error handler so I can easily see the state of the currently declared variables at the point the exception is thrown.  The problem is that I cannot find a way to replicate this dynamically in .NET.

My example below shows how the handler will be used:

```
 Private Sub TestMethod()
    Dim x As Integer = 301
    Dim y As String = "hello"
    Dim z As Boolean = True
    Dim a As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim b As Char = "c"c
    Dim c As Decimal = 0.45D

    Try
        x = 222
        ' Generate error here
        Throw New Exception("There has been an error")

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' code here to record variable names, types and values
    End Try
End Sub
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to run a single routine that will use see which variables are declared in the current scope, their types, and their values.

I have started to look at system.reflection and use MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() however, the nearest I have got to my desired effect is that I can list the types of declared variables but not their contents.  Using PropertyInfo brings me several different items from form size to the namespace, but not the declared variables I require.

I was wondering if anyone else has managed to find a way to do this using either VB.NET or C#, or if there are any 3rd party classes out there that can add this functionality.

Edit: in my half asleep state I had put the Try in the wrong place. The question still stands though as I'm getting the same issue as before. I can get the type of variable but not a name or value.  Should also add that it's strange that the debugger can do it in the IDE, but not in code.

Comment: You do realize that those variables have been lost when you got into the body of the catch, right?

Comment: oops!  my example was wrong.  I've edited the question and moved the Try to below the declarations.  Still can't make system.reflection give me the values though.

Comment: If all your variables are there in scope - why not just dump them right there in the Catch?

Comment: The debugger can do this using the debugger interface, search for mdbg (managed debugger). You will not be able to do this using reflection.